# How is the metaclass of a subclass determined?

Tags: python, metaclass

For the code below:

```py
class TestMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print(f'In TestMeta, class {cls}')
        type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)

class Parent(metaclass=TestMeta):
    pass

class Child(Parent, metaclass=type):
    pass
```

The output is:

```py
In TestMeta, class <class '__main__.Parent'>
In TestMeta, class <class '__main__.Child'>
```

In my opinion, when creating the class `Parent`, `TestMeta.__init__` will run, but why it runs again when creating the class `Child` which I have changed its metaclass as `type`? How is the metaclass determined when inheriting ***and*** passing a `metaclass`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think it should *not* be run? Both ``Parent`` and ``Child`` are instances of the metaclass, and creating an instance commonly invokes ``__init__``.

Comment: Hello, @MisterMiyagi . When I define class `Child`, I change its metaclass as `type`, so I think it should use `type` to create class `Child`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass):

> The appropriate metaclass for a class definition is determined as
> follows:
>
> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is used;
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is *not* an instance of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), then it is used directly as the metaclass;
> - if an instance of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used.
>
> The most derived metaclass is selected from the explicitly specified
> metaclass (if any) and the metaclasses (i.e. `type(cls)`) of *all*
> specified base classes. The most derived metaclass is one which is a
> subtype of all of these candidate metaclasses.

In your case above, the third bullet holds, as `type` is given as the explicit metaclass and there are base-classes.

According to the definition of *the most derived metaclass*, the candidates are: `TestMeta` and `type`. Since `TestMeta` inherits `type`, it is the most derived metaclass and is indeed the metaclass of `Child`.

To demonstrate the difference, the following code shows how we can *"force"* `Child` to get the specified `metaclass` instead of the inherited one:

```py
class TestMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print(f'In TestMeta, class {cls}')
        type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)

class OtherMeta(TestMeta):
    def __init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_):
        print(f'In OtherMeta, class {cls}')
        type.__init__(cls, classname, bases, dict_)

class Parent(metaclass=TestMeta):
    pass

class Child(Parent, metaclass=OtherMeta):
    pass
```

The output would be:

```
In TestMeta, class <class '__main__.Parent'>
In OtherMeta, class <class '__main__.Child'>
```

Notice that again, according to the definition of the most derived metaclass, this only works if `OtherMeta` itself is a subclass of `TestMeta`. Removing this inheritance relation will give the error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```